# Android Play Store Update Wait Time (08/2020)

Tags: android

I'm having an issue on the Google Play Store and I was just wondering if anyone could provide any input as my research did not answer my question:

I have a crucial update for Android that needs to be published but Google has been taking almost 4 days to review it. Is there any way I can expedite the review? This will become a major issue if it does not get published.

Thank you.

Comment: No, there is no way to expedite Play Store reviews.

Comment: @RyanM Interesting, thanks for your input.